# TreeMap <String,object> ClassCastException

Tags: java

```
my code:

TreeMap<String,Book> booksTree=new TreeMap<String,Book>(new StringCompare());
Book b1=new Book("b1");
booksTree.put(b1.getCode(), b1);
Book b3=booksTree.get(b1);
System.out.println(b3.toString());
```

i read in other post here that i have to add comparator so wrote  :

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class StringCompare implements Comparator<String>
{
    public int compare (String c1, String c2) 
    {
        return c1.compareTo(c2);
    }

}
```

and i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: maman18.Book cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at maman18.StringCompare.compare(StringCompare.java:1)
at java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.get(Unknown Source)
at maman18.Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

it's the first time i use TreeMap with strings and don't know how to use it very well, please help me fix this so the get function work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Book b3=booksTree.get(b1);  
--------------------------^
```

The parameter must be String

```
public V get(Object key) :
```

The method call returns the value to which the specified key (String in ur case) is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key.

Comment: my pleasure to help u dear :)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the get method expect a key which has the same data type as you defined your map (i.e `String` in your case).

So it should be:

```
Book b3=booksTree.get(b1.getCode());
```

This is specified in the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) :

> ClassCastException - if the key is of an inappropriate type for this
>   map (optional)

It says optional because for an `HashMap` per example, `get` will return `null`. So you would have a `NullPointerException` on the line `System.out.println(b3.toString());` instead.

But in the case of a `TreeMap`, this exception is [thrown](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29).

> ClassCastException - if the specified key cannot be compared with the
>   keys currently in the map

Answer (score 0):

Try with ,

```
TreeMap<String,Book> booksTree = new TreeMap<String,Book>();
```